# virtualenvwrapper.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - Python/Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

**What do I have to do to successfully launch virtualenvwrapper.sh?** 
**What do I need to put into my .bashrc?**

The *error message*:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable 
#When I launch the terminal I see it twice, when I launch it manually I see the error message only once.
```

I want to install Python/Django and followed [this manual](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/requirements.html):

- download and install python,
- install setuptools-8.2.1,
- install pip,
- pip django, pip pillow,
- sudo install virtualenv, sudo install
  virtualenvwrapper

*virtualenvwrapper.sh* can be found in (not in /usr/local/bin):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The *virtualenvwrapper folder* can be found in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
```

My *.bashrc* I edited as followed:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After studying related posts I tried:

- reinstall all packages via pip
- reinstall pip
- kill -9 to make sure all there are not too many open processes

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Should be something like (for me it is python3, but I see you are using python2):

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Comment: Yup, `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is just the shell script you source to add virtualenvwrapper's functions to your shell.  It doesn't make sense to set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` environment variable to it; that should point to the python interpreter virtualenvwrapper should use.